# Calculate Image Rotation - (0° 360°)

Tags: ios, swift, image, user-interface, math

I'd like to calculate the rotation of an image in degrees (**calculate affine transformation** ) .
This is what I got so far:

```
extension Double {
  var toDegrees: Double { return self * 180 / .pi }
}

let rotationAngle = Double(atan2f(Float(self.myView.transform.b), Float(self.myView.transform.a))).toDegrees
print(rotationAngle)
```

The "rotationAngle" I'm getting looks quite good but tbh I't is not:

But if I rotate the image about 0° or about 180° I get the same values (same for rotating the image about 90° **&&** -90° --> values are both **45°**):

[image: img]

EDIT: This is how I can apply rotation on my imageView:

```
self.ImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(.pi))
```

**How can I fix this to get a unique value for every rotation angle? (0° - 360°).**

EDIT:

See some more rotations (the first value is the `degree value` I've turned the image, the second one is the calculated `rotationAngle`):

[image: img]

EDIT 2:

```
0° --> rotationAngle: 0.249977666546474, transform.b: 0.004362960593833, transform.a: 0.999990482242134

-90° --> rotationAngle: -44.999557289943, transform.b: -0.999984511428548, transform.a: 0.00556568980525373

180° --> rotationAngle: 0.0352338243182017, transform.b: 0.00061494629500543, transform.a: -0.999999810920509

90° --> rotationAngle: 44.9995128937134, transform.b: 0.99998300906796, transform.a: -0.00582937178330692
```

Comment: Are you looking to determine the rotation portion of an affine transform?

Comment: Yes. I called it rotation angle but I will edit my question. @DavidRönnqvist

Comment: `CGFloat(-20)` looks already wrong, you have to specify the rotation angle in radians.

Comment: It was just an example but your right. Edited `-20 to .pi`! @MartinR

Comment: Actually your computation seems to be OK (assuming that there is no other transformation), only that the angle would be returned in the range -180...180. But I don't see how 45 should be returned for an image rotated by +/-90 degrees. – Can you show both the transformation matrix and your result for some problematic cases?

Comment: Yeah. I tried to get a solution for about 1 hour because I can also not find the error. No idea where.. Btw: Edited my question, see above. @MartinR

Comment: Show the values of `self.myView.transform` for those four cases.

Comment: Please have a look at my recent edit. @MartinR

Comment: But `Double(atan2f(-0.999984511428548, 0.00556568980525373)).toDegrees` from the second example evaluates to -89.6811078023194, not to -44.999557289943.

Comment: no comment ... You are right, I have found my mistake. MY MISTAKE. My extremely stupid mistake. (Declared a wrong variable and did not notice the whole time ... I'm a fool xD) @MartinR